# Send mail directly to new gmail inbox primary tab

Tags: php, email, gmail, inbox, tabbed

Our mailer open rates are gradually decreases now a days in Gmail. Our mails are landing in to Gmail's social inbox tab and not in Primary tab. How can we send our mails directly to Primary inbox tab in Gmail. Please help us to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. avoid using addresses like "no-reply@example.com" instead use something more personalized like "[unique-user-name]@example.com"
2. Request the user to create an conversation for the email sent out to them for first time.

   - offer points/ perks to the subscribers for doing so.
   - Once the user replies, Gmail is likely to treat your emails as personal/primary.